# How to calculate A intersection B?

Tags: probability

The probability that a student knows the correct answer to a multiple choice question is 2/3. If student does not know the answer, then the student will guess the answer. The probability of a guessed answer being correct answer is 1/4.

Given that the student has answered the question correctly, the conditional probability that the student knows the correct answer is ......

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me define some events:

$G$: Guessed answer is right.

$C$: Questions is answered correctly

$K$: The answer to the question is known.

$\overline K$: The answer to the question is not known.

It is asked for $P(K|C)$.

*Bayes rule*

$P(K|C)=\frac{P(K\cap C)}{P(C)}=\frac{\frac14}{P(C)}$

*Law of total probability*

$P(C)=P(K)\cdot P(G|K)+P(\overline K)\cdot P(G|\overline K)=\frac23\cdot 1+\frac13\cdot \frac14=\frac34$